# CMake. Ошибка линковки boost::filesystem с исполняемым файлом

Tags: c++, cmake, boost, build, cmakelists

При попытке слинковать boost::filesystem...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)

set(PROJECT_NAME BoostExample)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        BOOST_FILESYSTEM
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem.git
    GIT_TAG master
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(BOOST_FILESYSTEM)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

set_target_properties(
     ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
     CXX_STANDARD 14
     CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
     CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE boost::filesystem)
```

Получаю следующие ошибки:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Target "BoostExample" links to target "boost::filesystem" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Target "BoostExample" links to target "boost::filesystem" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_executable):
  Target "BoostExample" links to target "boost::filesystem" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at build/_deps/boost_filesystem-src/CMakeLists.txt:85 (add_library):
  Target "boost_filesystem" links to target "Boost::assert" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

В чем могут быть ошибки? Спасибо.

Comment: boostorg/filesystem.git - это репозиторий одной библиотеки (Modular Boost). Он нужен для разработки этой библиотеки. Вместо него следует скачивать из https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.78.0/source/

Comment: но судя по выводу, ему не хватает Boost::assert, может если ее подложить, оно и заведется? но я не уверен

Comment: Это не весь список зависимостей, там их еще штук двадцать. Просто не влезло.

Comment: Некоторые библиотеки бывают в отдельном варианте, например boost asio standalone. Однако этот boost filesystem к таким не относится и не может быть просто так использовать без прочих библиотек boost.

Comment: `vcpkg install boost-filesystem`